# STS 3.4.0 Gradle Support not working

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, gradle-eclipse, spring-boot

I am trying to get started on Gradle using STS 3.4.0 release, but when I try to add the Gradle support to my project all the options in the sub-menu are grayed out.  I tried removing the project and importing it as a Gradle Project, but when I click the Build Model button I get the following stacktrace:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/xxx/Documents/development/sample/build.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'sample'.
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer.create(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/gradle/api/Task;

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'sample'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:464)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$ConfigureProject.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$ConfigureProject.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:440)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:435)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:73)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DelegatingBuildModelAction.run(DelegatingBuildModelAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:103)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:59)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer.create(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/gradle/api/Task;
    at org.springframework.boot.gradle.SpringBootPlugin.addRepackageTask(SpringBootPlugin.java:45)
    at org.springframework.boot.gradle.SpringBootPlugin.apply(SpringBootPlugin.java:40)
    at org.springframework.boot.gradle.SpringBootPlugin.apply(SpringBootPlugin.java:1)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.apply(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.apply(AbstractProject.java:846)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$apply.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_366gv40hr9nngpsf8b524fqoup.run(/Users/xxx/Documents/development/sample/build.gradle:13)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 53 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.676 secs
```

I am guessing this is why the options are grayed out when I right-click on the project imported as a simple Eclipse project. There are no .java files in the project yet, and the `gradle` CLI command seems to run with no problems (ran `build`, `eclipse`, and `cleanEclipse` several times).  Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I Assume that you are using Eclipse. When you install gradle plugin in Eclipse, it uses an old version of gradle, 1.3 or 1.5. You can install the latest version of it, and supply its path to Eclipse. Suppose you install the latest version on C:\gradle. Open Eclipse preferences, and select Gradle. Update Gradle Distribution - Folder to C:\gradle. It should solve the problem.

Comment: I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.4.0, which is basically Eclipse with a bunch of Spring-specific add-ons.  I will try to point it to the latest Gradle, which I do have installed, and will report back.

Comment: I just edited it. Please select gradle from preferences. Then go to Gradle Distribution, and update the Folder to point to the home directory of gradle.

Comment: That seemed to work, but only if I imported as a Gradle Project.  For some reason, adding Gradle support via the right-click sub menu didn't work at all.

Comment: I believe this is the problem with the plugin itself. I know it doesn't work in some cases, I still couldn't figure out why.

Comment: It worked for me without re-importing, but doing this: right click on project > Configure > Convert to Gradle project...